# deserializing JSON vb.net response google maps api

Tags: vb.net

need some help here.
I'm not getting deserialize this json in vb.net.
I need the values lat : -21.4105261 and lng : -42.1956855.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "28460-000",
               "short_name" : "28460-000",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Rua Francisco Cardoso, 25 - Morro do Demétrio, Miracema - RJ, 28460-000, Brazil",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                 "lat" : -21.4105261,
                  "lng" : -42.1956855
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.4105429,
                  "lng" : -42.1956892
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.4105429,
               "lng" : -42.1956892
            },
            "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.4091855197085,
                  "lng" : -42.1943383697085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.4118834802915,
                  "lng" : -42.1970363302915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ElBSdWEgRnJhbmNpc2NvIENhcmRvc28sIDI1IC0gTW9ycm8gZG8gRGVtw6l0cmlvLCBNaXJhY2VtYSAtIFJKLCAyODQ2MC0wMDAsIEJyYXNpbA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Can anyone help?
This is the first time I use Json so I'm not experienced with it.
Ps: I have the json.net library installed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can use json.net and deserialize the json.
1/ Create the model

```
Public Class GooglCitiesResult
    Public Property city As String
    Public Property country As String
    Public Property country_code As String
End Class
Public Class GoogleGeoCodeResponse
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property results As results()
End Class
Public Class results
    Public Property formatted_address As String
    Public Property geometry As geometry
    Public Property types As String()
    Public Property address_components As address_component()
End Class
Public Class geometry
    Public Property location_type As String
    Public Property location As location
End Class

Public Class location
    Public Property lat As String
    Public Property lng As String
End Class

Public Class address_component
    Public Property long_name As String
    Public Property short_name As String
    Public Property types As String()
End Class
```

2/ call it in your controller

```
GoogleUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Paris,France&sensor=false&language=en"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Dim result = Await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(GoogleUrl)
Dim jsonGoogle As GoogleGeoCodeResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of GoogleGeoCodeResponse)(result)

Dim GoogleLatitude As String = jsonGoogle.results(0).geometry.location.lat
Dim GoogleLongitude As String = jsonGoogle.results(0).geometry.location.lng
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a custom class to represent the object you are looking to deserialize.. then you would do something like...

`Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer
Dim resp As List(Of cls_custom_class) = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of cls_custom_class))(json)`

IF you built the class properly, the Deserialize function should be able to map the JSON to your custom object and then you will have full access to whatever field/values you need.