# Google Maps Api V3 and parse Json Result

Tags: vb.net, maps

I download from
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=

a Json Result.

```
 Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
   Dim uri As Uri = GetGeocodeUri(address)

       Dim geocodeInfo As String = client.DownloadString(uri) 
            Dim test() As Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Result())(geocodeInfo )
```

i got always a json Error .

If i show the result in a browser , it looks like a well formated json.
But in my geocodeInfo i have

```
"{" & vbLf & "   ""results"" : " & vbLf & "   [" & vbLf & "      {" & vbLf & "         ""address_components"" : " & vbLf & " 



Public Class AddressComponent
    Public Property long_name As String
    Public Property short_name As String
    Public Property types As List(Of String)
End Class

Public Class Bounds
    Public Property northeast As Northeast
    Public Property southwest As Southwest
End Class

Public Class Geometry
    Public Property bounds As Bounds
    Public Property location As Location
    Public Property location_type As String
    Public Property viewport As Viewport
End Class

Public Class Location
    Public Property lat As Double
    Public Property lng As Double
End Class

Public Class Northeast
    Public Property lat As Double
    Public Property lng As Double
End Class

Public Class Result
    Public Property address_components As List(Of AddressComponent)
    Public Property formatted_address As String
    Public Property geometry As Geometry
    Public Property place_id As String
    Public Property postcode_localities As List(Of String)
    Public Property types As List(Of String)
End Class

Public Class Root
    Public Property results As List(Of Result)
    Public Property status As String
End Class

Public Class Southwest
    Public Property lat As Double
    Public Property lng As Double
End Class

Public Class Viewport
    Public Property northeast As Northeast
    Public Property southwest As Southwest
End Class
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [deserializing JSON vb.net response google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451009/deserializing-json-vb-net-response-google-maps-api)

Comment: Almost sounds like you want to be deserializing ````(Of Root)```` and not ````(Of Result)````

Comment: ````Dim test As Root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Root())(geocodeInfo)````